# Hive error CDH 5 "Error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.avro.io.DatumWriter"

Tags: hive, cloudera, hadoop-yarn

Hello i tried to perform easy request. but hive always return error:

```
Error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.avro.io.DatumWriter
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:274)
at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByNameOrNull(Configuration.java:1986)
at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:1951)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.serializer.SerializationFactory.add(SerializationFactory.java:70)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.serializer.SerializationFactory.<init>(SerializationFactory.java:63)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.getSplitDetails(MapTask.java:368)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:423)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:168)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1642)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:163)
```

I have CDH 5.3 and yarn installation.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this link https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SQOOP-542

This occur when avro jar file not present in classpath

Comment: Try to add important part of the link in answer.