# hadoop ERROR ON WORDCOUNT PROGRAM

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
 {
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    conf.addResource(new Path("/usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop/core-site.xml"));
    conf.addResource(new Path("/usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop/hdfs-site.xml"));
    Job job = new Job();
    //job.setJarByClass(WordCount.class);
    job.setJobName("WordCounter");

    job.setJarByClass(WordCount.class);
    job.setMapperClass(TokenizerMapper.class);
    job.setCombinerClass(IntSumReducer.class);
    job.setReducerClass(IntSumReducer.class);
    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path("/home/pramukh/eclipse/eclipseproj/hadoop/input/input.txt"));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path("/home/pramukh/eclipse/eclipseproj/hadoop/output.txt"));
//System.exit(0);
    System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
  }
```

This is my java hadoop wordcount example, which gives the following error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/apache/avro/io/DatumReader    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native
>   Method)   at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)  at
>   org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:1074)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.io.serializer.SerializationFactory.add(SerializationFactory.java:69)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.io.serializer.SerializationFactory.(SerializationFactory.java:62)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.split.JobSplitWriter.writeNewSplits(JobSplitWriter.java:117)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.split.JobSplitWriter.createSplitFiles(JobSplitWriter.java:74)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.writeNewSplits(JobClient.java:1030)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.writeSplits(JobClient.java:1041)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.access$700(JobClient.java:179)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:959)     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:912)  at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:742)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:912)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:500)     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:530)   at
>   hadoop.WordCount.main(WordCount.java:66)
>       Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.avro.io.DatumReader   at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)     at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: First of all, you don't need to shout (caps) :)

Comment: Here is a possible solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30675014/hive-error-cdh-5-error-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-apache-avro-io-da

Answer (score 0):

If the rest of your code in this program is corrected;
I suggest you check the path
The OutputPath folder can't be exist
I tried your code changes the file path ,the code can run normally

```
FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path("hdfs://localhost:9000/wordcount/test.txt"));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path("hdfs://localhost:9000/wordcount/out"));
```